# Color style property not applying in div, in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla, inline

[solved: it was a weird css issue in the template, thanks to all.]

[Last update: what seems the problem to be: 'color' style property is not inherited inside 'div p' in joomla2.5.]

The red color is not applying:

```
<div style="color:red;">
<p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Instead, this works:

```
<div style="color:red;">
paragraph
</div>
```

Problem only in Joomla2.5.
The same code works in plain text files.
Why this mess? Makes you feel very unsafe.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is, why the div's color is not red, as it ought to.

Comment: What does firebug or developer tools tell you is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Something overiding your css.

try this

```
   <div class="para">
   <p>paragraph</p>
   </div>

 .para>p{    
    color:red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both instances of "paragraph" should be red: http://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/br7u3y5k/

Look at the `<div>` and its CSS in the browser console. Either the `<div>` is not rendering the way you think it is, or there could be additional lines in your stylesheet that are interfering with the color of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Testing and testing: It is not a matter of CSS overrides. The problem happens only with the 'color' property, either the style defined inline or with a class from an external stylesheet. It happens only inside Joomla.

Comment: <div style="color:red;">This gets red.<p>This does NOT get red.</p></div>. Madness!